# Side Effects in R programming the walk() function

Tags: r

I'm sure my question seems a little basic, but somehow I am not able to understand the concept of how the Walk() function prevents the side effects.
Lets say in the example:

```
x (1,"a",3)
print(x)
```

would lead do a side effect the prints the value in the console and changes the environment. Now to avoid this we substitute it with the walk function under the purr package by  x %>% walk(print) to avoid this but still the values are displayed in the console, isn't this a side effect ?
How would this be different?
Moreover we can use the walk2 function and iterate the function over a set of arguments and providing a set of results. Now this would somewhere change the state of the system how is this not a side effect?

So my underlying doubt is how does the walk() function avoid side effects successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so sure the walk() function avoids side effects. 
From the documentation:

```
walk() calls .f for its side-effect and returns the input .x.
```

So the side effects happen, but the input is returned (invisibly).

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.3/topics/map

Comment: Oh okay that resolves my confusion, thanks for your help regarding the subject